# How to login into router with default credentials using python

Tags: python, dns, router

I have TP Link router (WR841N).I want to login into my TP link router and needs to change primary and secondary DNSusing script.

I tried to login using below script but not succeeded:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib

def main():
    userName = 'admin'
    pcPassword = 'admin'
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    login_data = urllib.urlencode({'userName' : userName, 'pcPassword' : pcPassword})
    resp = opener.open('http://192.168.0.1/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm', login_data)
    print(resp.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then how to change primary and secondary dns using script.

Comment: I think you need [**selenium**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) here.

Comment: if your router has ssh/telnet support that is likely to be much easier to use to do this - you will need to find the command-line equivalent commands to change the settings. I use tomato and that has 'nvram set var value' and 'nvram commit' commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CookieProcessor doesn't set POST header, obviously.
You need to set Content-Type and Content-Length to match your login_data.

I would recommend you to install the opener you built using urllib2.install_opener(), and then use request:

```
r = urllib2.Request('http://192.168.0.1/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm')
r.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
r.add_header("Content-Length", str(len(login_data)))
r.add_data(login_data)
u = urllib2.urlopen(r)
print u.read()
u.close()
```

Then you have to continue with filling all other forms to change what you want.

If cookies aren't managed by javascript, you will be able to do it. If they are, perhaps even then if you examine the code carefully and extract cookie results manually from javascript code. I did it before.

But, yeah, SSH or telnet or rlogin would be easier than HTTP. To continue using HTTP, take a look at Requests package, it can be helpful, and make your code smaller. It includes session managing for you.

Adding urlencoded type to content-type might not help if login form has enctype attribute set to something else. (plain text or multipart).

I don't think that'll be a case, but if it is you can still do it with a bit more work.